# Está sendo feito upload da imagem sem extensão

Tags: php, upload

Coloquei um código PHP para upar imagens, as imagens não estão sendo salvas no diretório com o código abaixo:

```
$post_id = $db->insert($query);
$ext = explode('.', $_FILES['img']['name']);
$path = "../content/img/".$post_id.".".$ext[count($ext)]-1;

$img = move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"], $path);
```

var_dump $path  `int -1`

var_dump do $ext

```
     array (size=2)
  0 => string 'nome-da-imagem' (length=14)
  1 => string 'jpg' (length=3)
(Já que é uma imagem jpg)
```

var_dump $img  `boolean true`

Porém quando modifico a variável $path para apenas `$path = "../content/img/".$post_id;`
var_dump dá `string '../content/img/60' (length=17)`

Aí salva (60 porque é o ID desse novo post), mas sem a extensão.

Comment: Ja tentou usar o $ext[1] já que ele retorna um array. Pq pelo var_dump ele retorna duas posições 0 e 1 pra recuperar alguma posição precisa usar $ext[0] ou $ext[1].

Comment: O -1 que vc ta usando precisa ficar dentro do indice e não fora $path = "../content/img/".$post_id.".".$ext[count($ext)-1];

Comment: Ambas as formas funcionaram!!

Comment: Se funcionou considere a resposta que coloquei abaixo

Comment: Uma sugestão é proteger o upload pq vc abrindo um acesso ao servidor e ai se alguem subir um script php ja sabe né :( . faça restrições com a tipo de extensão, tamanho, criptografe com sha1 ou o que vc escolher etc.

Comment: No momento estou criando as funcionalidades, realmente necessito fazer essas restrições, obrigado pelo toque.

Comment: @GeovaniC, existe alternativa melhor a explode, use a função [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pathinfo.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente usar assim:

```
$path = "../content/img/".$post_id.".".$ext[count($ext)-1]; # o -1 dentro do índice assim ele diminui com o count da variável.
```

Ou:

```
$path = "../content/img/".$post_id.".".$ext[1];
```

Comment: Deu certo, a imagem está sendo salva com a extensão correta agora. :)

Comment: Vote na questão pra ajudar os demais :) e avalie como correta :)